# My registered namespace stops to work after logout from BE

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I have my site package extension `toolbox` with a lot of custom ViewHelpers. For not violating DRY rule I registered my own namespace (with [global namespace import tip](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html#global-namespace-import)) for recognizing it within Fluid instead placing at the beginning of each template as usually in `typo3conf/ext/toolbox/ext_tables.php` and in general that works:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fluid']['namespaces']['toolbox'] = ['BIESIOR\Toolbox\ViewHelpers'];
```

I can (or rather could) use my VH's like `<toolbox:someViewHelper />`, however after moving page  from development to production (the same machine, just switched domains) suddenly I get an exception like:

`TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Parser\UnknownNamespaceException`

> `Fluid parse error in template Standard_action_Orangeheader_2c41396366318874342b894b22eff7acb311cc0c, line 2 at character 1. Error: Unknown Namespace: toolbox (error code 0). Template source chunk: {toolbox:containerEscape(condition: data.tx_mask_escape, start: 'true')}`

What's frustrating this problem disappears when I'm logged to BE as an admin and preview the FE in the same browser, as fast I'll logout from BE *and/or* visit required FE page in another browser, the exception comes back.

As mentioned during development this problem didn't occur, after logout.

ViewHelper is used in page's template included in main TypoScript with `FLUIDTEMPLATE` cObject.

Had somebody such weird behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ext_localconf.php` instead of `ext_tables.php` for it.

Not sure, but I think `ext_table.php` is Backend End (BE) context only, but you need the ViewHelper in the FE Context.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationFiles/Index.html#ext-tables-php): `ext_tables.php` is not always included in the global scope of the frontend context. This file is only included when a TYPO3 Backend or CLI request is happening or the TYPO3 Frontend is called and a valid Backend User is authenticated.